# Flex - SuperAccordion

Tags: apache-flex

I want to use a SuperAccordion GUI component. I.e. an accordion, where sereval windows can be opened simultaneously.

I found this:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/tourdeflex/web/#sampleId=19370;illustIndex=0;docIndex=1

However, I can get the code... Flex does not know about a component 'SuperAccordion".

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your link contains all the code you need... SuperAccordion is composite component defined in this very example.

Edit: Actually, no. There is a library used: ws.tink.flex.containers, hosted at: http://tink.googlecode.com/svn-history/r49/trunk/ws/tink/flex/containers/

You can use **svn** to get it: **svn checkout http://tink.googlecode.com/svn-history/r49/trunk/ws/tink/flex/containers/ [folder to store it]**

Edit: or even simpler: http://code.google.com/p/tink/downloads/list

Comment: He already has a SuperAccordion see:

<containers:SuperAccordion id="accordion" color="0x323232" width="100%" height="100%">
            
       bla bla , some code ( see link)

</containers:SuperAccordion>



He already has it in the `components`, I do not. Thus he uses it. I want to get the code for one of these....

Comment: I downloaded the file SuperAccordionHeader.as for here:  http://tink.googlecode.com/svn-history/r49/trunk/ws/tink/flex/containers/superAccordion/SuperAccordionHeader.as    but it has errors and can not be compiled.... line: "import ws.tink.flex.containers.SuperAccordion;" flex can not import this.... If I could have use it, then there would be no need for all of this. I would have just used the SuperAccordion from ws.tink.flex.containers.SuperAccordion

Comment: what is this:  http://code.google.com/p/tink/downloads/list ? This is some kind of swc file.... ?

Comment: Ok, I downloaded the swc. How do I plug it to my code and use it? thanks

Comment: get swc into "libs" folder in your project (or anywhere, but it is better to keep things in place). Open menu Project/Properties/Flex Build Path/Add SWC.

Comment: Ok, my /lib directory is already in the "library path", great! :) Now how do I use this SWC and the SuperAccordion?

Comment: Nope :( How do I prompt Flex to a container "SuperAccordion" ? p.s. I restarted my Eclipse to reload the swc

Comment: In mxml, you can start typing <SuperAcco... then use autocomplete. In ActionScript: var acc:SuperAcco... (it should show class name, if swc is imported correctly)

Comment: Hmm... nope. This probably means I did not import correctly... How to check it? I go to Prohect->Properties->FlexBuilderPath->LibraryPath->AddSWC
If I expand the TinkSpark, it shows the TinkSpark.swc but it also shows Source attachment(none), Link Type merged into code, Auto extract swc (n/a)

Comment: Spark? If you are using Flex 3 framework, you need TinkMX.swc. TinkSpark is for Flex 4.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work, however, I have some strange compilation err, I can not over come ( see my answer below)
I also tried  inserting in some other code and the err is still there...

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.israfil.mojo:maven-flex2-plugin:1.3:compile-swf (default) on project redaction-review-tool: Result of flex2.tools.Compiler execution is: '1'. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: This is something that got to do with the swc files... Have you seen such an err?

Comment: No, I'm using FlexBuilder (and assumed you are too). You had to point out your environment and Flex version details...